# X11 escaped color codes appearing in tmux shells

Tags: x11, tmux, i3, rxvt, urxvt

In Fedora 39, with i3 + urxvt + tmux, each time I `tmux new-session` or `tmux attach-session`, something prints the following characters to the terminal shell, presumably with broken or misinterpreted escape sequence:

```
user@hostname:~ $ /fe00/fd00^[^[]11;rgb:0100/0200/0300^[^[user@hostname:~ $
```

The pattern repeats each time I reattach to this session with `tmux attach-session` (without inputting anything on the terminal):

```
user@hostname:~ $ /fe00/fd00^[^[]11;rgb:0100/0200/0300^[^[]10;rgb:ff00/fe00/fd00^[^[]11;rgb:0100/0200/0300^[^[]10;rgb:ff00/fe00/fd00^[^[]11;rgb:0100/0200/0300^[^[]10;rgb:ff00/fe00/fd00^[^[]11;rgb:0100/0200/0300^[^C
```

I first encountered this bug after upgrading to Fedora 39. This seems to be a bug somewhere between tmux and urxvt, which I run in i3. My primary goal is figuring out what workaround I need to use and where I should be filing a bug for this behavior. I can't seem to eliminate the root cause, other than to switch from `urxvt` to another terminal emulator entirely (which suggests to me that it's a bug in Fedora's `rxvt-unicode` package, but I would think I'd be able to demonstrate that by changing some `rxvt` / X11 configuration).

My `~/.Xresources` includes (this is where the 4 digit color codes are coming from):

```
[...]
*foreground: #fffefd
*background: #010203
[...]
```

I have tried deleting every other aspect of my `~/.tmux.conf`, `~/.Xresources`, `~/.bashrc` (including `PS1` and `COMMAND_PROMPT`), and `~/.bash_profile` to no avail.

Removing my `~/.Xresources` does not resolve the issue. `root`, via `su - su root` from a urxvt session as my normal `user`, experiences the same issue without any user-specific (i.e. `root`-specific) shell, tmux, or X11 configuration in `/root/`.

I've also tried adding `set -x` to `/etc/profile` to determine where at a system-level this is occurring. It seems to be occurring *while* `/etc/profile` is executing, but not as a result of anything *in* `/etc/profile` (it's asynchronous). For example, if I add a `set -e; sleep 1` at the very beginning of `/etc/profile`, it appears in the trace during the sleep:

```
+ sleep 1
^[]10;rgb:ff00/fe00/fd00^[^[]11;rgb:0100/0200/0300^[+ '[' -x /usr/bin/id ']'
+ '[' -z 1000 ']'
++ /usr/bin/id -un
+ USER=user
```

Comment: What is your TERM setting? I suspect you need some form of ```set -ga terminal-overrides ",st-256color:Tc,stterm-256color:Tc,xterm-256color:Tc"``` to force tmux to interpret the True Colour escape codes.

Comment: Thanks - that's where my research went too. Outside of tmux it's `rxvt-unicode-256color`, and inside tmux it's `tmux-256-color`. Changing the value inside tmux's config hasn't had any effect with the values I've tried, including the value you suggested.

Comment: I ended up working around this issue by switching from `rxvt-unicode` to `alacritty`

Comment: @Dolph fwiw I have found a way to configure my `.tmux.conf`.  In my situation I am running into it as I start a _VSCode_ Terminal session. `10;rgb:cccc/cccc/cccc11;rgb:1818/1818/1818` is my output.  I tracked it down but let me know if an answer is needed still.

Comment: I found a workaround here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=293022

Comment: @tijko I have the issue you describe with my VSCode integrated terminal showing `10;rgb:cccc/cccc/cccc11;rgb:1818/1818/1818` whenever I attached to tmux. How did you solve that?

Comment: @kung-fu-kenny I have added an answer to reflect some changes that _worked_ for me and several other people that I have been in communication with.  There are issues but slightly different depending on the usecase.

Comment: @Dolph you might not have had to switch by trying to adjust the settings I mention in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using *TMux* in coordination with a couple of terminal-emulators depending on my environment that I'm using at the time.

That said, I've come across some configuration issues very similar to the one mentioned.  Having a session start under *VSCode* and its integrated terminal there is this dump:

```
[tijko@tijko ~] 10;rgb:cccc/cccc/cccc11;rgb:1818/1818/1818
```

To show exactly what it looks like I've attached this image:

[image]

Now going into my `.tmux.conf` I found [`escape-time`](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#escape-time)

> Set the time in milliseconds for which tmux waits after an escape is
> input to determine if it is part of a function or meta key sequences.
> The default is 500 milliseconds.

My default was set to 10 milliseconds and by increasing this I no longer have the "escape sequence" dump.

`.tmux.conf`:

```
  23   │ setw -g xterm-keys on
  24   │ set -s escape-time 200                     # faster command sequences
  25   │ set -sg repeat-time 600                   # increase repeat timeout
  26   │ set -s focus-events on
```

You can see I've set my new `escape-time` to `200` milliseconds and it fixed the issue.